# Object.class/object.getClass() (what is the difference)

Tags: java

`Customer.class` and `cust.getClass()` <strike>work, but `cust.class` does not</strike>?  What is the difference?

```
public class Customer() {

}


public class Test {

    public Test() {
        Customer cust = new Customer();

        test(Customer.class);
        test(cust.getClass());
    }


    public <T> void test(Class<T> clazz) {
        System.out.println(clazz);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you think it should work? It's not defined in the Java spec.

Comment: What is the error? Could you paste it here.

Comment: Seems like your question is *Why not obj.class?? I want obj.class!!!*

Comment: Yeah, why can't we have obj.class!! Anyway, I get it now. For some reason I though it was a valid statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited after OP changes**

Let's redo the example:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        Test t = new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        Customer customer = new FastFoodCustomer();
        test(Customer.class); 
        test(customer.getClass());
    }


    public <T> void test(Class<T> clazz) {
        System.out.println(clazz);
    }

}

class Customer{

}

class FastFoodCustomer extends Customer{

}
```

This gives the following output:

```
class Customer
class FastFoodCustomer
```

`getClass()` method is inherited from `Object` ancestor class. It will tell you what class the object is. If you want to know a given instance class you need to call `thatInstance.getClass()` method. If you call `Customer.class` you are getting just `class Customer` because you are asking what class `Customer` is. But an object `Customer` can be a `Customer` but also it can be any subclass of it (i.e. FastFoodCustomer in this example).

Your other example `cust.class` doesn't work because `cust` doesn't have any `class` attribute by itself nor inherited.

Answer (score 1):

`Object.class` is a "pseudo static field" of Object and returns the class object for the named class.  It generates essentially zero code.

`obj.getClass()` is a virtual method of Object and returns the ACTUAL class object for the object in the `obj` reference.  It generates an actual call to inspect and retrieve the class (which may be a subclass of the reference's declared class).

I'm not sure if `obj.class` will compile, but if it does it's a "compiler swizzle" equivalent to coding `Object.class` -- in general, when you use a reference in place of a literal class name, you get the equivalent as if you'd coded the reference's declared class name.

Comment: Hmm, no. `class` is not a field (pseudo or not) and actually does not mean anything alone. `Object.class` as a whole is a class literal (see JLS about class literals : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2 ). `obj.class` will not compile : because of the `.class` part, the compiler considers `obj.Class` as a class literal. Hence, it searches the `obj` class and does not find it.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle - The compiler considers `obj.Class` to be a reference to a field named `Class` in the object referenced by "obj" (assuming "obj" is a declared reference, which is certainly how most folks would interpret it).

Answer (score 0):

Construction obj.class will not compile at all, because .class will works only for classes. Like String.class, for instances of class you need to call getClass()

Comment: ok, this was a contrived example, I was actually using a real class like `Customer`

Comment: But note that `objRef.someStaticMethod()` *will* compile.  It's inconsistent at best.

Comment: @HotLicks .class isn't a static method, agree?

Comment: Right.  `class` is a read-only static field.  Very much analogous.

Answer (score -1):

`Object class` has a reference to a class, but `obj` has the reference to an instance only, so you should use the method `obj.getClass()`

**PS:** If downvoting, please let me know where is my fault.

Comment: what is the difference between obj.getClass() and Object.class then, why should I prefer obj.getClass()?

Comment: @jax do you understand the difference between `class` and `instance`?

Comment: yes I do, but I don't understand why I should prefer the instance obj.getClass() over Object.class

Comment: @jax you couldn't sure about obj instance at runtime. So, for example it could be subtype of Object, not object itself. To me, obj.getClass() is more flexible

Comment: @SeniorJD: Pretty much. I deleted my comment once I realised that!

Comment: @AndrewMartin and others: So if I'm write, why am I have the `-1` mark? :(((