# Java Object.class and x.getClass

Tags: java

I have a method like this:

```
public Object load(Object type) {
...
}
```

Note that the parameter is an Object-type.

I have several classes that are using the *loadConfiguration* method. Inside the method I need to know the class, so the value for *MyObject.class* is needed.
Well, because I have an *Object*, this is not possible and *type.getClass()* also throws an exception, because is just gives me *java.lang.Class* and not the real one.
One possibility would be to use *instanceof* functionality but I would like to keep it as general as possible.

Any ideas for this? I also had look [to this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185399/object-class-object-getclass-what-is-the-difference).

Thank You!

Comment: Do you know which classes is going to call `locad(Object obj)` ?.. if so may be try `instanceOf` ..

Comment: Sounds like you want Java Generics my friend. One question. *Why* do you NEED to know the type of the object? What object specific functionality are you calling?

Comment: @looser Nope - thats the point

Comment: You are saying that "parameter is an Object-type." but I'm still not sure what your type object represents. You can either leave load(type) and call it with a real runtime object in which case .getClass() will return the runtime type for that object, or replace it with load(Class c) and call it a bit different

Comment: @user2252775 It won't be possible to find out the type of the object if you can pass any random object to the method. Its only possible via Generics and that too if you restrict the type of objects being passed.

Comment: @Blitzkr1eg It represents an object of some arbitrary class

Comment: Object o = new ArrayList<String>();
System.out.println(o.getClass()); //prints class java.util.ArrayList
So if your param is actually an instance of an object, then type.getClass() should return whatever that instance is

Comment: "type.getClass() also throws an exception" which exception?

Comment: @yogi Well the exception is caused, because "java.lang.Object" is returned, which is not usable in that scope.

Comment: @christopher Generics solved that problem, thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure in your example exactly what is going on. I believe in your example the parameter `type` is a Class object, so you can just cast it.

```
public Object load(Object type) {
Class<?> clazz = (Class<?>)type;
...
}
```

Calling code would then look like

```
blah.load(MyObject.class);
```

If in fact you need to know the class of the type the method is being invoked on, you can simply call

```
Class<?> clazz = this.getClass()
```